# php-oci8 encoding issue

Tags: php, oracle, character-encoding, apache2, oci8

Similar questions have been asked, but the regular solutions do not work for me. Probably I am missing something. I am about to loose my mind :(((

As you can understand it from the title, I have an **oracle** database with non-ascii content. I want to query/display it with **php** using **oci8**.

First of all, the database is in ISO8859P9, i.e. the query

```
select parameter, value from v$nls_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY')
```

returns

```
NLS_LANGUAGE        AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY       AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSER    WE8ISO8859P9
```

So I have set up NLS_LANG variable accordingly, i.e. getenv("NLS_LANG") returns "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9".

I inserted `AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-9` to /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset file, and I always included `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9">` in head section of html content of php files. So when I check via firebug, I see that the "Content-Type" header for a response is "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9".

Lastly, I have a line as `default_charset = "ISO-8859-9"` in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file, and in the core section of the output phpinfo(), I see that default_charset is ISO-8859-9.

After all these stuff, when I retrieve a string with a character `İ` in it and echo it, it is shown as '?'. That is the problem!!! When I query `select dump(nameofthatstring, 16)...`, I see that its byte value is DD, i.e. correct according to 8859-9.

I am not sure whether it is relevant but, I will give a final detail: When I enter a character `ı` in a form and submit it via ajax in GET, it is converted to %FD, i.e. the 8859-9 corresponding value, no problem.

When I urldecode it and echo it, it is again ok, I see `ı`. But when I have a query with a string containing `ı` in its where clause (after receiving the ajax request), it returns empty set.

However, if I select the rows using CHR(253), the rows are selected correctly, but printing these rows again results in '?' characters.

I am really stuck. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
$database = "(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXX)(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=sname)))";
```

First, I have tried this:

```
oci_pconnect($username, $password, $database, "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9");
```

But it did not solve, so I set NLS_LANG variable and changed to the following:

```
oci_pconnect($username, $password, $database);
```

Nothing changed...

Comment: Can you post the code where you connect to oracle from php ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try connecting like this:

```
putenv("NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9");
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=
     (ADDRESS_LIST=
       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
         (HOST=$dbhost)(PORT=$dbport)
       )
     )
       (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$dbname))
 )";
 $conn = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpasswd, $db);
```

Set the variables `$db*` according to your configuration.

Comment: OCILogon is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ocilogon.php), and I prefer persistent connections, so I did not change oci_pconnect. But putenv did the trick :). But how? getenv('NLS_LANG') already returned the same value, and it was listed also in phpinfo() page. Isn't it a bit weird?

Comment: Yes, It's strange, but I had your same similar problem (mine with spanish charset) and resolved it this way. I used oci_logon() at that time now it seems deprecated.

Comment: You savior!  I want to kiss every part of you!!

Comment: I'm glad this helped you! (especially if you have to use Oracle by obligation like me) anyway your upvote is more than enough appreciation! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are in a windows environment.

I had the same issue and I fixed it by
* creating a windows environment variable
NLS_LANG FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8ISO8859P1
* adding these line to my httpd.conf
SetEnv NLS_LANG FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8ISO8859P1

NB : Replace FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8ISO8859P1 by appropriate value

Comment: I was not in a windows environment, and by the way the project is dead now :)